# What is the basis for sorting unanswered [story-identification] questions?

Tags: discussion

I was taking a look through the list of unanswered [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions the other day, and I noticed that, though I thought that the list was sorted high-to-low by vote, the [tail end of the list](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification?page=64&sort=unanswered&pagesize=15) has some surprisingly high-scored posts on it.

What is the basis on which the list is being sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '[unanswered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification?page=64&sort=unanswered&pagesize=15)' question list only shows questions that have **no upvoted answers**, cross-sorted by descending number of votes.

The top of the list has those questions that haven't been answered at all (zero answers) whereas the bottom of the list has questions with one or more downvoted answers.

As you can see, the [first 58 pages](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification?page=58&sort=unanswered&pagesize=15) are those with no answers, then those with an increasing number of downvoted answers, culminating with what is arguably [the worst question on the site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64917/movie-about-humans-living-on-another-planet-and-are-at-war-with-each-other); no upvotes and only a single downvoted answer

Comment: Pretty close. The internal logic appears to number of answers (ascending), then score (descending, then creation date (descending), then ID (descending). However, that doesn't explain the questions with fewer answers sorting after questions with more on the last page...

Comment: @Shog9 - I blame you personally. Go fix it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this covered somewhere on main meta? I spent 15 minutes searching and couldn't find it. (cc @Shog9)

Comment: If it is, I couldn't find it either, @rand. Kinda surprised by that.